# File php.ini configuration on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, apache

I am experiencing a strange problem with PHP configurations file php.ini on Mac OS X. I have created a phpinfo file. Calling it in the browser shows the PHP settings with -

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc

Loaded Configuration File: /private/etc/php.ini

However upon editing the php.ini file at this location, (and restarting Apache of course) the changes are not reflected in the PHP settings as well as the phpinfo file.

E.g.: changing the bcmath decimal digits, changing timezone settings, etc. Is there another primary location from where Apache will pick up the settings file?

Comment: Can you mention the package name that u using in ur system ? MAMP pro or XAMP ?

Comment: How do you install php and apache?

Comment: @jimca  - I am not using any package. Am using the default php apache on osx.

Comment: Consider this - If I temporarily delete the php.ini from /etc and then restart apache and reload phpinfo the php settings are still displayed. Does'nt this means that apache is still able to read the ini/configurations file from somewhere. Where could this be?

Answer (score 7):

I'm using native Mac OS X Apache 2 with [Homebrew taps from josegonzales](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php).

To quote my system administrator friend, "the answer should lie in restarting PHP-FPM instead of Apache. Apache uses mod_fastcgi to connect to PHP via a port or socket that PHP-FPM runs PHP with."

You need to load/unload the [p-list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list) file associated with your PHP-FPM install. First check *~/Library/LaunchAgents* Not there? Mine was located here:
`/usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.26/homebrew-php.josegonzalez.php53.plist`

It's restarted like this:

```
launchctl unload -w /usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.26/homebrew-php.josegonzalez.php53.plist && launchctl load -w /usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.26/homebrew-php.josegonzalez.php53.plist;
```

I added the following to my *~/.bash_profile* file so that I can restart PHP-FPM when I restart Apache. The command to invoke the following is "apachectlrestart"

```
function apachectlrestart () { sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist && sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist && launchctl unload -w /usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.26/homebrew-php.josegonzalez.php53.plist && launchctl load -w /usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.26/homebrew-php.josegonzalez.php53.plist;}
```

<sub>This is an old post, but I had this problem and scoured the Internet to no avail, so I answer here for posterity.</sub>

Comment: Posterity thanks you a whole bunch @glassdimly! Worked for me.

Comment: Also, great looking website @glassdimly, very nice.

Comment: Of all the solutions this worked for me. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

[Jeremy John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733342/file-php-ini-configuration-on-mac-os-x/22103961#22103961) helped me to fix this problem.

**Problem:**

- `'Loaded configuration file'` shows `'/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini'` in `phpinfo()` output, and my module (imagick) is not getting loaded by PHP.
- I tried manually including my module in the main *php.ini* file and restarting Apache, but `'Loaded configuration file'` did not update.
- I tried killing all instances of Apache and restarting Apache - still same.
- I tried renaming my `php.ini` to `php.ini_` and restarted Apache, but `'Loaded configuration file'` is still showing the old `php.ini` file.

**Solution:**

- After reading Glassdimly's answer above, I tried these steps:
- `launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php70.plist`
- `launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php70.plist`
- And boom - it worked!
- Next I set up shortcut function inside my `~/.bash_profile`:

  ```
   # restart php-fpm
   function restart_fpm(){

       plist=~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php70.plist

       launchctl unload -w $plist
       launchctl load -w $plist

       echo "PHP 7 fpm restarted"
   }
  ```
- `source ~/.bash_profile` loads the new function into the current shell

Answer (score 0):

Restarting your Apache HTTP Server server from the services panel will reflect your new changes made...

Comment: I think you missed the part in the brackets. I am already restarting the server each time after editing the php.ini file from - Internet and wireless -> Web sharing -> Turn off and Turn On. Another point is if I temporarily move the php.ini file out of the /etc folder the php settings are still displayed on calling the phpinfo file , however this time the loaded configurations file has changed.

Comment: I think if i m not wrong then your browser is making cache of the page. Try deleting cache and reload the page again.....