# Changes in my php.ini are not reflected - "memory_limit" seems to get overridden by another file

Tags: php, macos, apache

I'm on Mac OS X and I'm using PHP. I need to increase the memory_limit from 256M to 1024M. However, when I modify the value in the *php.ini* file, the changes do not get reflected.

Normally, I think my *php.ini* file is located in

```
/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
```

as mentioned on my *phpInfo.php* page. Other values get updated, but not this one. Therefore, it seems that *memory_limit* gets overwritten by another file. Is there a way to determine where it gets overwritten?

Comment: Did you reboot the server after making the changes?

Comment: yes. Only memory_limit does not get updated.

Comment: Grep (or otherwise search) your code for `memory_limit`.  It's certainly possible another file is overwriting the setting.

Comment: That did it, thank you. There was a file in php.d that redefined memory_limit.

Comment: php_info will show if there are any additional .ini files being loaded that could be overriding this... but honestly if you have a script that even needs 256M then you seriously need to look at rewriting your script as deploying that to a web server could be dangerous as it could be used to DOS the server.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mac OS X default Apache with [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) [PHP-FPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Installation_and_configuration) and mod_fastcgi and I had this exact, puzzling problem.

My answer lay in restarting PHP-FPM separately through unloading/loading the plist file. See *[File php.ini configuration on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22103961/3358444)*

Answer (score -3):

Set the memory limit programmatically:

`ini_set('memory_limit','16M');` or

Do a [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) and see where your loaded .ini file is located. And edit the memory limit there.

Comment: That's what I said, it was overwritten and had to use grep to find the file that was overwritting it.