# Php not loading extension

Tags: php, apache, ini

This is my second post (original https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33463744/php-not-loading-extensions-or-anything-from-php-ini) - Im new to this whole thing and accidently hit answer instead of reply.

I am running on a mac with apache loaded from xampp.

Im trying to get an extension (ZMQ) loaded in php. It is loaded fine in the terminal php (checking it with php-i). However in a browser it is not loaded. I edited the php.ini (based on the location of the php.ini (as said in path from phpinfo) and no matter what I do it doesnt load. It actually seems like editing the php.ini file does nothing.

I have restarted the apache server. Any ideas, 
Thanks so much for your help, JB

Comment: check `phpinfo()`. it'll tell you WHICH .ini file(s) were loaded. you may be editing the wrong one.

Comment: Your previous post exists as a question. You didn't need to post it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php not loading extensions (or anything from php.ini)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33463744/php-not-loading-extensions-or-anything-from-php-ini)

Comment: the phpinfo stated which php.ini (only one) and I am editing that one.

Comment: So it seems like this is an issue w/ mac: see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733342/php-ini-configuration-on-mac-osx

Comment: But I have no plist file to unload?  Also I tried changing my location of php.ini in httpd.conf but that wouldnt updated.  I think that my configure command is the cause - the directory seems to be hard coded: -with-config-file-path=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc'